# git - controlling user access to specific git repositories

Tags: linux, git, authentication, repository

I am new to the implementation of git and i had a requirement where i need to control user access to specific git repositories.

For ex: I have 3 different projects for which i create 3 different git repositories and grant access permissions to specific users based on the projects they are working. I have tried the following way but all the users created on Linux server are able to access all the repositories created under each user. It is not getting restricted to specific Linux User.

1. Create three Linux users, one for each repository:  Proejct1, Project2, and Project 3
2. Login into each user and create the bare Git repository
3. For each user, create ~/.ssh/authorized_keys  (/home/Project1/.ssh/authorized_keys) and add the public SSH key for each user that should have access

I am not sure what needs to be done to provide access to the git repository only to the user who has created it and do not allow other users to access the Git repository.

Please suggest me the list of steps that needs to be implement to control access to specific Git repositories?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about UNIX file permissions than about Git. I can think of two ways to achieve this:

---

For the solution you mentioned in the top post, with `repoA` as the repo name:

1. Create the repo-specific account (`useradd -m repoA`)
2. As root, make sure that the repo account's home is only readable or writable by the repo account (`chmod 0700 /home/repoA`)
3. Create the repo in `/home/repoA`
4. Make sure that the right user owns the repo (`chown -R repoA /home/repoA/repoA`)
5. Add user public keys to `/home/repoA/.ssh/authorized_keys` - managing these files will be an ongoing task
6. Have your users clone the repo with `git clone repoA@server:repoA`, or have them update their existing copies with `git remote set-url origin repoA@server:repoA`

---

For another solution, also with `repoA` as the repo name:

1. Create a group for the repo (`groupadd repoA`)
2. Add the appropriate users to the group (`usermod -aG repoA alice` will add `alice` to the group) - managing group memberships will be an ongoing task
3. Create the repo folder with `mkdir -p /opt/repoA` (for example)
4. `chgrp repoA /opt/repoA` (change group ownership)
5. `chmod ug+rwx,g+s,o-rwx /opt/repoA` (user and group can read/write/execute, others cannot, and the group bits are persisted no matter which specific user alters the contents)
6. Have users add their own keys to their own `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
7. Have users clone the repo with `git clone alice@server:/opt/repoA` or `git clone bob@server:/opt/repoA` etc., or use `git remote set-url` to modify existing copies

---

And for yet another option, use a hosting package such as GitLab Community Edition or Gitea, which will give a nice interface for users as well as for admins.

Comment: How to create different user groups with different access permissions to the repository? For ex. I have a group which performs read, writer and execute and another group with only read permissions. How can i set these groups to the repository such that each individual groups access it accordingly? Please suggest

Comment: The easiest answer short-term is to implement an ACL on filesystems hosting your repos. The easiest answer long-term is to install something like GitLab or Gitea (there are others) and manage everything there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion !! I have implemented ACL and able to provide different access permissions to different user groups. Able to clone the repository and push the changes too with different users..

Comment: Even i tried setting group permissions using the commands 
sudo chown -R username:groupname /path/to/git  
sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/git

This approach also worked for different user groups. Can you please suggest whether ACL is the best approach or the traditional Linux file system permissions ?

Comment: ACL would be better if you want some people to have read/write access, others to have read-only access, and others to have no access at all. Otherwise, mode 0775 should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions!!!. I am able to setup different access permissions to user groups using ACL.